# ArgoCD change default admin username

Tags: cicd, argocd

ArgoCD comes with default `admin` username.
I would like to change the default `admin` username for security reasons.
Is it possible?
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [official documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/user-management/).

You can do it with ArgoCD CLI:

```bash
# if you are managing users as the admin user, <current-user-password> should be the current admin password.
argocd account update-password \
  --account <name> \
  --current-password <current-user-password> \
  --new-password <new-user-password>
```

This is not documented but I guess the passwords are actually stored in a Secret.

That being said, using the admin account is not recommended. You should disable the admin account and create individual accounts or, better, use SSO with your existing user base.